# Initialising numerical properties from a text-based properties file

Tags: java, validation, spring, configuration

This is a Spring Framework-based datasource instantiator which reads its properties from the Spring Framework context, i.e. the values are initially all `String` from properties files and numbers have to be tested for presence and validity.

Normally it would be totally superfluous in Spring Framework because the purpose of Spring Framework is to allow Java developers to by-pass it all. However sometimes as in this case, something is different and it has to be done manually.

My main concern with this method is the repeated use of the `couldBe` variable which is an attempt to make it more readable.

`couldBe` is the possibly hopefully valid number retrieved from the properties file, which could in fact be invalid.

This is all that is in the class:

```
private final Pattern testForInt = 
    Pattern.compile(GeneralUtils.REGEX_TEST_FOR_INT);

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tardis.datasource")
public Map<String, String> dataSourceProperties() {
    // Spring populates the map with properties prefixed as above
    return new HashMap<>();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    Map<String, String> props = dataSourceProperties();
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(props.get("driver"));
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(props.get("username"));
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(props.get("password"));
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(props.get("url"));
    String couldBe = props.get("maximumPoolSize");
    if (couldBe != null && testForInt.matcher(couldBe).find()) {
        dataSourceConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(couldBe));
    }
    couldBe = props.get("maxLifeTime");
    if (couldBe != null && testForInt.matcher(couldBe).find()) {
        dataSourceConfig.setMaxLifetime(Long.valueOf(couldBe));
    }
    couldBe = props.get("leakDetectionThreshold");
    if (couldBe != null && testForInt.matcher(couldBe).find()) {
        dataSourceConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(Long.valueOf(couldBe));
    }
    couldBe = props.get("connectionTimeout");
    if (couldBe != null && testForInt.matcher(couldBe).find()) {
        dataSourceConfig.setConnectionTimeout(Long.valueOf(couldBe));
    }
    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks context. Please tell us what this code does, and why it exists. Also, the title should state the purpose of the code, rather than your main concern about it. (See [ask].)

Comment: OK, that was unexpected! Just goes to show you should always rtfm, or in this case the How To Ask a Good Question. Lucky I got 100 points free :O

Comment: It's a common thing to provide a separate Interface for a specific Configuration (so you can switch implementation and mock it easier in test cases). So I recommend to provide a `DatasourceConfiguration` interface with `int getMaxLifeTime()` and do the magic within the implementation (e.g. a private `getInt(String property, Integer default)` method).

Comment: That would certainly clean up this code, and I'm wondering why your comment isn't an answer (I'm new here). Also, it occurs to me that I already have a specific Configuration - `HikariConfig` - so I need to let Spring initialise that, instead of the map, by changing all my property names - as long as that bit of magic with the property prefix annotation works.

Comment: Actually if I let Spring automatically initialise `HikariConfig` I suspect it will silently fail to initialise `int` values when the property value is invalid.

Comment: No, I can't persuade Spring to initialise a `HikariConfig` object. It breaks the whole `Spring Boot` initialization process, presumably because `Hikari` is one of the default connection pools that it tries to set up based on the parameters I supply. It's not RAD anymore.

Comment: Having numeric properties in spring boot never was a problem
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/